# Is it possible to preprocess stderr to obfuscate sensitive data

Tags: stderr

Let's consider a server with a lot of applications running and potentially emitting errors to stderr. Those applications being heterogeneous, it is impossible to guarantee that none of them emit sensitive information to the standard streams - it could be possible for self-maintained applications but impossible for third party ones anyway.

I'm wondering if it is possible to have some kind of pre-processing whenever something is written to stderr to apply there some obfuscation logic.

Does it make sense? What would be the best way to handle this?